# how to quit disk usage analyzer?

Tags: virtualbox, disk-usage, disk-management

I'm running ubuntu 16.04.6 virtual machine on my ubuntu 16.04.6 host machine.
My virtual machine (VM)'s disk is full so I press 'examin' as it suggested. 
Then I see this 'Disk Usage Analyzer' in my command terminal window as below.

[image]

My question is, HOW CAN I QUIT THIS PROGRAM (without quiting the original command window)?

Comment: Try using Ctrl-Z

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to start it in the first place. It doesn't have its separate window so there should be a command line command. I'll try later.